# VM access to serial port / hardware

Tags: virtualization, hardware

Can an application running on a VM access a physical COM port in order to communicate with a device plugged into it?

I have tried it in VirtualBox, and no joy. I wondered if enterprise virtualization solutions would allow it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VMWare ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/overview.html) will allow you to connect a physical serial port to a guest VM.

[image: Serial Port Configuration]

Comment: You are a gentleman. So, will that just show up as a COM port in my guest Windows OS? Can I choose the port number?